# Different timing with large array assignment

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, packed-arrays

Consider the following example

```
n = 10^8;
AbsoluteTiming[
 A = ConstantArray[1., n]; // anyFunc;
 A[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = -1.;
]
```

> {0.388108, Null}

```
n = 10^8;
AbsoluteTiming[
 B = ConstantArray[1., n];
 B[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = -1.;
]
```

> {0.738504, Null}

```
A == B
```

> True

Why is the first approach faster? The only difference is, there is an arbitrary function outside the first one. I am using Mathematica 12 on windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: Set `$HistoryLength=0`

Comment: @ciao Wow, that _does_ help, but I wonder why it does so. Can you explain that. It is not like `DownValues[Out]` were totally cluttered...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'd bet that the history tracking of the kernel keeps a reference to `B` but not `A` that causes the tensor to be copied when some elements are changed to `-1.`  That the tracking would be turned off when one sets `$HistoryLength = 0` makes sense; but why a reference to `B` exists but not to `A` -- or why a reference to `B` exists at all -- I cannot explain.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: I have no idea, and the days of being motivated to dig way under the weighted covers to find out have faded. I found this and similar behaviors years ago, as did others, but the how/why of this particular case... beats me. Perhaps a Wolfram engineer might chime in.

Comment: This `$HistoryLength = 0` can be relevant in `wolframscript`, cause there you cannot have access to history even though is set to infinity by default. It would make sense to set it to zero if it gives performance increase.